# Next Js in prod mode gives 404 when open subputh directly (i18n)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

In production mode, after building, when open subpath directly, Next JS app gives 404.
For example, when I open domain.com/page, gives - 404. But, when I open domain.com/en/page it works.

My next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    i18n:{
        locales:["en", "ru"],
        defaultLocale: "en",
    }
}
```

One of my page components:

```
import { MainLayout } from "../components/MainLayout";
import en from "../locales/en/en.js";
import ru from "../locales/ru/ru.js";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function About() {
  let router = useRouter();
  const { locale } = router;
  const t = locale === "en" ? en : ru;

  return (
    <MainLayout title={"About page"}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="content">
          <h1>{t.about}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </MainLayout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your _app.js
You have to write this line;

```
export default appWithTranslation(YourApp);
```

And you should define localePath in your i18n object in next.config.js
like this :

```
localePath: path.resolve("./public/locales")
```

After you can access your translations in component or page like this;

```
const { t } = useTranslation('common');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I'm leaving this [answer from stackoverflow](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/721#issuecomment-876962618) for anyone that is having this error using Docker, in my case it was the solution to my problem.

Be sure to copy the next.config.js file in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./next.config.js /app/next.config.js
```